# How to create table defined in sqlalchemy schema in the Heroku server?

Tags: python, heroku, sqlalchemy, database-schema, turbogears2

I have a very simple app that I'm building with Python, SQLAlchemy, PostgreSQL and Turbogears 2.3.

The app works in my local machine, where I use SQLite. However, when I upload it to Heroku, I don't know how to create there the PostgreSQL tables that TurboGears2 uses for authentication and validation: tables like User, Gruoups, Permissions.

I see the schema is defined in a file called `auth.py` which looks like this:

```
....
from sqlalchemy import Table, ForeignKey, Column
from sqlalchemy.types import Unicode, Integer, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relation, synonym

from example2.model import DeclarativeBase, metadata, DBSession

class User(DeclarativeBase):

    __tablename__ = 'tg_user'

    user_id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(Unicode(16), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email_address = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    display_name = Column(Unicode(255))
    _password = Column('password', Unicode(128))
    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User: name=%s, email=%s, display=%s>' % (
            repr(self.user_name), repr(self.email_address), repr(self.display_name))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.display_name or self.user_name
...
```

So my question is how can I create these tables automatically in the Heroku server? What commmand or script do I have to execute?

Edit: Thanks to JPub's answer, I read on the docs, how to do it from console:

```
$ gearbox setup-app -c production.ini
```

And to do it in Heroku it should be:

```
$ heroku run 'gearbox setup-app -c production.ini'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have any experience with turbogears, but reading through documentation you have two options.

Direct creation:

http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/turbogears/gearbox.html#setup-app

Writing your own migrations:

http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/turbogears/migrations.html

Comment: Thank you very much JPub. I don't how I missed that from the documentation.